# Within block not executed inside match_unless_raises and custom matcher

Tags: rspec, capybara

I was trying to extract some of my code into a custom matcher:

```
matcher :have_nav_headers do |headers|
   match_unless_raises do |page|
     headers.each do |header|
       expect(find('.navbar-default')).to have_content(header)
     end
   end
end

matcher :have_nav_headers do |headers|
   match_unless_raises do |page|
     within('.navbar-default') do
       byebug
       headers.each do |header|
         expect(page).to have_content(header)
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

The first matcher will perform just fine, but I'll never hit the debug if I try instead to use the second version, and the tests will automatically pass.  I can't see any difference between the two other than the use of 'within', and for some other custom matchers I'm writing, I'd really prefer to be able to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec provides a `be_within` matcher that it aliases as `within`.  Unfortunately if that is called with a block it doesn't raise an error, and since calling it just creates a matcher (but never evaluates it) it doesn't actually do anything with what it's passed either.  Recent versions Capybara install a proxy to try and route to the correct version of `within` based on parameters passed, so either update to a current version of Capybara or try calling `within_element` (instead of `within`) which is an alias of the Capybara provided version of `within`.  You should also be able to call it on `page` to ensure the correct version is called ( `page.within ...`)

Comment: Both page.within and within_element worked perfectly.